# How could I use selenium without actually open the browser and get the table content? Python

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I am trying to run a python program in a web database to get the results table. My question is how could I get the results without actually opening a browser? And is there an easier way to get the table results? I want to get the bottom table value(e.g.BCS class, solubility, dose.etc.). (The bottom part of the results does not have td.text come along, so I cannot use the find next sibling command.) Thank you! Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.ddfint.net/search.cfm')
search_form=driver.find_element_by_name('compoundName')
search_form.send_keys('Abacavir')
search_form.submit()

page= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
page.find("td", text="Lowest Solubility (mg/ml):").find_next_sibling("td").text
```

Comment: cURL?:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module. There's a problem to get **BCS Class (logP)** text because HTML is broken in both **BCS Class** table data. Solution is to use `html5lib` as a parser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'http://www.ddfint.net',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Referer': 'http://www.ddfint.net/search.cfm',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}

data = {
    'compoundName': 'Abacavir',
    'category': '',
    'subcategory': '',
    'Submit': 'Search'
}

response = requests.post('http://www.ddfint.net/results.cfm', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
print(page.find("td", text="Lowest Solubility (mg/ml):").find_next_sibling("td").text)

# get header row
header_row = page.find("td", text="Country List:").find_parent("tr")
# get columns names, remove : and *
header_data = [re.sub("[:*]", "", td.text.strip()) for td in header_row.find_all("td")]

country_index = header_data.index("Country List")
solubility_index = header_data.index("Solubility")
bcs_class_clogp_index = header_data.index("BCS Class (cLogP)")
bcs_class_logp_index = header_data.index("BCS Class (logP)")

row = header_row
while True:
    # check if next row exist
    row = row.find_next_sibling("tr")
    if not row:
        break

    # collect row data
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in row.find_all("td")]
    print(row_data[country_index], row_data[solubility_index],
          row_data[bcs_class_clogp_index], row_data[bcs_class_logp_index])
```

---

Code with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'http://www.ddfint.net',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Referer': 'http://www.ddfint.net/search.cfm',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}

data = {
    'compoundName': 'Abacavir',
    'category': '',
    'subcategory': '',
    'Submit': 'Search'
}

response = requests.post('http://www.ddfint.net/results.cfm', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
print(page.find("td", text="Lowest Solubility (mg/ml):").find_next_sibling("td").text)

# get header row
header_row = page.find("td", text="Country List:").find_parent("tr")
# get columns names, and remove : and *
header_data = [re.sub("[:*]", "", td.text.strip()) for td in header_row.find_all("td")]

# loop while there's row after header row
data = []
row = header_row
while True:
    # check if next row exist
    row = row.find_next_sibling("tr")
    if not row:
        break

    # collect row data
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in row.find_all("td")]
    data.append(row_data)

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header_data)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to get the solubility, BCS class for each country listed, (at the bottom part of the table). Can you please advise? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this community, don't know about this. Did I accept the answers?

Answer (score 7):

You could try adding the `--headless` argument to `ChromeOptions` to tell the browser to not render.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Do you have comments for getting the table results also? Thanks!

Comment: To get the value for 'Lowest Solubility' in the table from your example, I would just use plain Selenium / Python syntax to do so: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Lowest Solubility')]]/td[2]")`. If BeautifulSoup has an option to locate by XPath, you can use the XPath string here to locate your element as well.

Comment: I agree xpath would be the easy way to get the data. If I am not taking it wrong, beautifulsoup does not support xpath. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct about that, which is why I prefer the python / selenium way :) another user has suggested using the Requests library, which may be more helpful for you here. Best of luck with your automation.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the selenium headless by adding an option `(--headless)` like that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

and about iteration through a table, you can select all table rows and take only the relevant one like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
myrow = rows[5]
```

Comment: Thank You Daron. I tried your code, somehow I got an error message of 'NameError: name 'By' is not defined'? Sorry, I am very new to web scrapping.

Comment: You’ll need to add `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` to the top of your file for this to work.